# Check whether an array is empty

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following code

```
<?php

$error = array();
$error['something'] = false;
$error['somethingelse'] = false;

if (!empty($error))
{
    echo 'Error';
}
else
{
    echo 'No errors';
}

?>
```

However, `empty($error)` still returns `true`, even though nothing is set.

What's not right?

Comment: Works correctly for me in PHP 5.3 on Windows - I get `Error`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139301/php-0-as-a-string-with-empty
check answer no 2

Comment: Is the output of this code "Error" or "No errors"?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? When I run this code, I get Error which is correct because the array has keys and hence is not empty. Do you want false to somehow equate to "not there"?

Comment: I get Error too.

I wanted it so that if $error['something'] = true, then only will $error return true.

Answer (score 425, accepted):

There are two elements in array and this definitely doesn't mean that array is empty. As a quick workaround you can do following:

```
$errors = array_filter($errors);

if (!empty($errors)) {
}
```

`array_filter()` function's default behavior will remove all values from array which are equal to `null`, `0`, `''` or `false`.

Otherwise in your particular case `empty()` construct will always return `true` if there is at least one element even with "empty" value.

Comment: array_filter($input) also removes empty arrays from $input.

Comment: This could be trimmed down to `if (array_filter($errors)) {}`

Comment: array_keys($errors, true) would do the same as this filter, I think.  (Most people don't use the second argument, but you can search with it.)

Comment: or array_sum(array_values($errors)) would just tell you how many errors you have.

Answer (score 72):

You can also check it by doing.

```
if(count($array) > 0)
{
    echo 'Error';
}
else
{
    echo 'No Error';
}
```

Comment: You don't need to count the elements or use empty(). A one-liner like php -r 'echo array() ? "T":"F";'
 will show the truthiness for an empty or non-empty array.

Comment: empty() handles FALSE and isset(), so you may want empty() for that reason.

Answer (score 16):

Try to check it's size with `sizeof` if `0` no elements.

Comment: `sizeof` is an alias of `count`.

Comment: Reminder: `sizeof` is on the deprecation list, see https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecations_php_7_1

Comment: In this case, count  (or sizeof) would return two, due to the two values which are set to false.

Answer (score 16):

PHP's built-in [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function checks to see whether the variable is empty, null, false, or a representation of zero. It doesn't return true just because the value associated with an array entry is false, in this case the array has actual elements in it and that's all that's evaluated.

If you'd like to check whether a particular error condition is set to **true** in an associative array, you can use the [array_keys()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) function to filter the keys that have their value set to true.

```
$set_errors = array_keys( $errors, true );
```

You can then use the empty() function to check whether this array is empty, simultaneously telling you whether there are errors and also which errors have occurred.

Answer (score 8):

array with zero elements converts to false

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php

Answer (score 5):

> However, empty($error) still returns true, even though nothing is set.

That's not how `empty()` works. According to the [manual](http://php.net/empty), it will return true on an *empty* array only. Anything else wouldn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

From the PHP-documentation:

> Returns FALSE if var has a non-empty and non-zero value.

The following things are considered to be empty:

```
"" (an empty string)
0 (0 as an integer)
0.0 (0 as a float)
"0" (0 as a string)
NULL
FALSE
array() (an empty array)
var $var; (a variable declared, but without a value in a class)
```

Comment: Source http://php.net/manual/de/function.empty.php

Answer (score 2):

function `empty()` does not work for testing empty arrays!
example:

```
$a=array("","");
if(empty($a)) echo "empty";
else echo "not empty"; //this case is true
```

a function is necessary:

```
function is_array_empty($a){
foreach($a as $elm)
if(!empty($elm)) return false;
return true;
}
```

ok, this is a very old question :) , but i found this thread searching for a solution and i didnt find a good one.

bye
(sorry for my english)

Comment: This is a best way of array empty checking. Or you can use
$set_errors = array_keys( $errors, true );

Answer (score 2):

hi array is one object so it null type or blank

```
   <?php
        if($error!=null)
            echo "array is blank or null or not array";
    //OR
       if(!empty($error))
           echo "array is blank or null or not array";
    //OR
     if(is_array($error))
           echo "array is blank or null or not array";
   ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't replicate that (php 5.3.6):

```
php > $error = array();
php > $error['something'] = false;
php > $error['somethingelse'] = false;
php > var_dump(empty($error));
bool(false)

php > $error = array();
php > var_dump(empty($error));
bool(true)
php >
```

exactly where are you doing the `empty()` call that returns true?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
if(empty($myarray))
echo"true";
else
echo "false";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, even if the individual items within an array or properties of an object are empty, the array or object will not evaluate to empty using the `empty($subject)` function. In other words, cobbling together a bunch of data that individually tests as "empty" creates a composite that is non-empty.
Use the following PHP function to determine if the items in an array or properties of an object are empty:

```
function functionallyEmpty($o)
{
  if (empty($o)) return true;
  else if (is_numeric($o)) return false;
  else if (is_string($o)) return !strlen(trim($o)); 
  else if (is_object($o)) return functionallyEmpty((array)$o);

  // If it's an array!
  foreach($o as $element) 
    if (functionallyEmpty($element)) continue; 
    else return false; 

  // all good.
  return true;
}
```

Example Usage:

```
$subject = array('', '', '');

empty($subject); // returns false
functionallyEmpty($subject); // returns true

class $Subject {
    a => '',
    b => array()
}

$theSubject = new Subject();

empty($theSubject); // returns false
functionallyEmpty($theSubject); // returns true
```

Comment: This doesn’t work for at least inputs containing bool(true) values. Better write it like this: https://pastebin.com/DnFtDWgH