# php check is array is empty

Tags: php, arrays

How to check if array like this

`array(3) { [0]=> array(0) { } [1]=> array(0) { } [2]=> array(0) { } }`

is actually empty ? Because for me this is an empty array but for the empty() this is an array with 3  elements and for count this is a array with length 3 .. so is there a way to do it without foreaching the array ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why don't you want to `foreach()` the array?

Comment: Why have `foreach()` when you can do it in 1 line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if(!array_filter($array)){
  // empty
}
```

([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php))

Comment: +1 Clever.  Note it will only work for two-dimensional arrays (like OP).  Three dimensional arrays (array of arrays of arrays) would look something like `array_walk($array, 'array_filter') && !array_filter($array)` (untested)

Comment: That would be [`array_walk_recursive()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) (3D+)

Answer (score 3):

It is also stated here

[Check whether an array is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328983/php-check-if-an-array-is-empty?rq=1)

use `array_filter();`