# insert post in custom post type in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to update it but in one condition if post is already exist then update it if not then insert it.

```
  $values = "SELECT post_id FROM `wp_postmeta` where `meta_key` = 'embed_code'      AND `meta_value` ='$vid->embed_code' ";
    $metavalues = $wpdb->get_var($values);
     echo '<pre>';
    print_r($metavalues);


  if ($metavalues !=='') 
         {   

            $postID = wp_insert_post(array(
                      'ID'  =>  'post_id',
                'post_content' => $vid->description,
                'post_title' => $vid->name,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_type' => 'labelv',
                'post_category' => array($label->name),
            ));
            add_post_meta($postID, 'original_file_name', $vid->original_file_name);
            add_post_meta($postID, 'publishing_rule_id', $vid->publishing_rule_id);
            add_post_meta($postID, 'player_id', $vid->player_id);
            add_post_meta($postID, 'embed_code', $vid->embed_code);

            add_post_meta($postID, 'duration', $vid->duration);
            add_post_meta($postID, 'external_id', $vid->external_id);
            add_post_meta($postID, 'preview_image_url', $vid->preview_image_url);
            add_post_meta($postID, 'time_restrictions', $vid->time_restrictions);
            add_post_meta($postID, 'updated_at', $vid->updated_at);

            add_post_meta($postID, 'hosted_at', $vid->hosted_at);
            add_post_meta($postID, 'ad_set_id', $vid->ad_set_id);
            add_post_meta($postID, 'status', $vid->status);
     }
   else
        {    
          wp_update_post(array(

                'post_content' => $vid->description,
                'post_title' => $vid->name,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'post_type' => 'labelv',
                'post_category' => array($label->name),
            ));

            update_post_meta($postID, 'original_file_name', $vid->original_file_name);
            update_post_meta($postID, 'publishing_rule_id', $vid->publishing_rule_id);
            update_post_meta($postID, 'player_id', $vid->player_id);
            update_post_meta($postID, 'embed_code', $vid->embed_code);

            update_post_meta($postID, 'duration', $vid->duration);
            update_post_meta($postID, 'external_id', $vid->external_id);
            update_post_meta($postID, 'preview_image_url', $vid->preview_image_url);
            update_post_meta($postID, 'time_restrictions', $vid->time_restrictions);
            update_post_meta($postID, 'updated_at', $vid->updated_at);

            update_post_meta($postID, 'hosted_at', $vid->hosted_at);
            update_post_meta($postID, 'ad_set_id', $vid->ad_set_id);
            update_post_meta($postID, 'status', $vid->status);
      }
```

Comment: if ($metavalues !=='')  having syntax error. Seems metavalues is an array, so check empty($metavalues). Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328983/check-whether-an-array-is-empty