# empty($_POST['var']) returns true when the input value is '0'

Tags: php, html, post, input

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php: ‘0’ as a string with empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139301/php-0-as-a-string-with-empty)

I have an input in a form like so

```
<input name='var' type='number'>
```

When the form is submitted, input is sent to a PHP file through POST. 
On the PHP file, it checks to see if the input is filled out by checking

```
empty($_POST['var'])
```

When I enter '0' (zero) into the textbox and submit the form, the PHP code returns '1' for empty($_POST['var']) even though I have tried print_r($_POST) and 'var' clearly has the value of '0'.

Is this supposed to happen? Do I just need to also check for == 0 for this exception? Thanks.

Comment: Yep, [that's documented](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php). Zero is an "empty" value in string, int, and float forms.

Comment: If you need to code around the zero case, use `if (empty($_POST['var']) && !is_numeric($_POST['var']))`

Comment: Thanks for the documentation link, didn't see that list before. :)
Is there a way to mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: You can't accept  comment.  Rather than answer, I have linked an already existing question that covers the same topic and +1'd yours. Yours may eventually be closed with a link to the other.

Answer (score 3):

To check whether the field is filled or not, please use `isset($_POST['var'])` instead of `empty($_POST['var'])`.

Comment: It has its own caveats though. `isset()` will return `TRUE` on an empty string, which for the purposes of a `$_POST` key may not be the intended behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `empty` only to check whether it is empty string or string only contains blank char.

Use like this:

```
function isEmpty($key) {
  return isset($_POST[$key]) && trim($_POST[$key]) === '';
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice on blank spaces, I am already using regex for validation.

Answer (score 0):

empty() returns true if the variable being checked is undefined, 0, empty string '', false, an empty array, or null.  So the result you are seeing is 100% correct.

In the case where 0 is a legitimate value, use is_set().