# Wordpress php undefined index with form posting to db

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, forms

I am building a very small form for a wordpress widget. The form is just a drop down select input that allows users to select their business type - this is then stored in the wp_usermeta table in the database.

The dropdown is actually selected on registration, so this form is more of an opportunity for users to change the value.

Here is the php I am using to create the form:

```
<?php 
$user = wp_get_current_user();        
$selected = get_user_meta( $user->ID, 'i_am_a', true ); 
?>

<form method="post">        
<h3>I am a...</h3>
        <select name="i_am_a" id="i_am_a">
            <option value="musician" autocomplete="off" <?php echo ($selected == "musician")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>Musician/Artist</option>
            <option value="band" autocomplete="off" <?php echo ($selected == "band")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>Band</option>
            <option value="photographer" autocomplete="off" <?php echo ($selected == "photographer")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>Photographer</option>
            <option value="business" autocomplete="off" <?php echo ($selected == "business")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>Small Business</option>
            <option value="other" autocomplete="off" <?php echo ($selected == "other")?  'selected="selected"' : '' ?>>Other</option>
        </select>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="change" class="button"/>

</form>
<?php
    $i_am_a = $_POST['i_am_a'];
    update_user_meta( $user->ID, 'i_am_a', $i_am_a );
?>
```

Notice: Undefined index: i_am_a in /home/.../layers-whitelabel.php on line 90

Line 90 is as follows:

```
$i_am_a = $_POST['i_am_a'];
```

How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Since this form has no `action`, I assume that if you submit the error is gone, right? If so, think about it, you are trying to use `$_POST` on a form that is yet to be sent, hence, `undefined` for that key...

Comment: if (!empty($_POST["i_am_a"]))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: @FirstOne yes once submitted the error goes. I added action="" to the form but still show the error.

Comment: @wuno where do I put that snippet?

Comment: Try the answer I gave in place of your current declaration of I_am_a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your variables. Or use [isset()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to check if they are declared before referencing them, as in:

```
$i_am_a = isset($_POST['i_am_a']) ? $_POST['i_am_a'] : '';
```

Comment: Perfect, just what I needed. I actually find that when the page reloads after submitting, the selected option isn't correct - do I need to use isset in my options too?

Comment: What do you mean the selected option is not correct?

Comment: You should move the last two lines above the $selected variable line. Because you are trying to get the updated meta value, before it is being updated.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
  $i_am_a = isset($_POST['i_am_a']) ? $i_am_a = $_POST['i_am_a'] : 0;
```

Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13042188/2218253) for the explanation of using 0 to check.

Comment: This answer was flagged, but I voted to keep it, however, I recommend that you add a bit of a description about what your answer is doing. (It might not be so obvious to people who might find this question useful.)